# Não consigo alterar o valor do gráfico com JS

Tags: javascript

Bom, eu peguei um gráfico de um template que eu uso, ele está mencionando o atributo `canvas` com um ID, eu achei esses ID em um arquivo js (**main.js**), e alterei os valores, para mudar no gráfico, **porém não mudou...**

Eu não entendo nada de JS, se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei grato.

**Gráficos no HTML:**

```
 <!-- GRÁFICOS-->
                       <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="au-card m-b-30">
                                    <div class="au-card-inner">
                                        <h3 class="title-2 m-b-40"></h3>
                                        <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

  <!-- END GRÁFICOS-->
```

**Main.js:**

```
(function ($) {
  // USE STRICT
  "use strict";

try {
    //bar chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");
    if (ctx) {
      ctx.height = 200;
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        defaultFontFamily: 'Poppins',
        data: {
          labels: ["2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Pacientes",
              data: [35, 44, 47, 79, 120, 145, 70],
              borderColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.9)",
              borderWidth: "0",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)",
              fontFamily: "Poppins"
            },
            {
              label: "Funcionarios",
              data: [20, 22, 30, 33, 36, 50, 40],
              borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.09)",
              borderWidth: "0",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.07)",
              fontFamily: "Poppins"
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
            labels: {
              fontFamily: 'Poppins'
            }

          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                fontFamily: "Poppins"

              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                fontFamily: "Poppins"
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    }


  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

**O gráfico que não muda:**
[image: Não funciona...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo por favor quando for fazer uma pergunta relacionado a uma lib especifica favor informar isso na pergunta para que possa ser um pouco mais claro, assim todos podem te ajudar. Creio que esteja usando a lib **chartjs** e realmente ela parece estar correta... Porém eu acho que você está na tabela errada... Não estou conseguindo ver relação entre a **labels** nos codigo com as exibidas na tela. Como por exemplo **Pacientes** que não esta na tabela.

Em todo caso segue um exemplo de uma tabela base... Para entender melhor sugiro que consulte a documentação. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Faça um teste e cole a base disso no lugar da sua tabela, se caso ainda não houver mudança me diga.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta, é essa lib mesmo aparentemente, sou novo nessa área. Então, o nome **Pacientes** não está aparecendo, o gráfico não muda, o que eu posso estar fazendo de errado? E como posso estar na tabela errada se esta mostrando `barChart`?

Comment: @SamuelVerissimo resposta editada acima

Comment: Eu até coloquei na mesma página esta documentação sua, porém, nem foi exibido... O que será que é?

Comment: Podem ser diversos fatores que por um trecho de código não pode ser verificado, te aconselho a verificar as dependências (pacotes instalados), porém, você precisara saber um pouco como funciona o gerenciador de pacotes (npm, npx, yarn) instalados em sua app...

Comment: Obrigado por tentar me ajudar Rafael, isso fez eu ir pesquisar e tentar entender um pouco sobre. Por algum motivo quando eu redireciono para algum script para carregar o gráfico, não funciona. Deixei junto com o HTML, e também não estava importando a biblioteca aparentemente... [Charts.js CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/chart.js)